# Data does not update after using executeUpdate()

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

So I have the following code to update a table.

```
@Override
public SalarySupplementModel update(SalarySupplementModel obj) {
    EntityManager em = super.getEntityManager();
    Query qry = em.createQuery("UPDATE SalarySupplementModel s "
        + "SET s.advanceDeduction = :adv, s.cit = :cit, s.allowance = :ia, "
        + "s.specialAllowance = :isp, s.insurance = :ins, s.others = :ot, "
        + "s.tds = :tds, s.transportAllowance = :ta, "
        + "s.vehicleDeduction = :vd WHERE s.salSupId = :sid");

    qry.setParameter("adv", obj.getAdvanceDeduction());
    qry.setParameter("cit", obj.getCit());
    qry.setParameter("ia", obj.getAllowance());
    qry.setParameter("isp", obj.getSpecialAllowance());
    qry.setParameter("ins", obj.getInsurance());
    qry.setParameter("ot", obj.getOthers());
    qry.setParameter("tds", obj.getTds());
    qry.setParameter("ta", obj.getTransportAllowance());
    qry.setParameter("vd", obj.getVehicleDeduction());
    qry.setParameter("sid", obj.getSalSupId());

    qry.executeUpdate();        

    return obj;
}
```

However, after I save it, the update do not show up until I restart the server.

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "not show up"?

Comment: Sorry wrong wording.  I mean the data is not updated when I try to reload the data.

Comment: How are transactions handled there? Does the data get into the database? What means "after I save it"? In which context is the code called? Does the code even get called?

Comment: Yes it shows up fine in the database, however, it doesn't show the effect in the application.  It just show the old data.

Comment: read the docs for JPQL UPDATE queries, no instances are updated in memory.

Comment: Any round about way that I can achieve it?  I looked through some many sites but still nothing.  Can I do something to the returned object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a stale version of the object in L2 cache, and because you are performing an update via JPQL it is not reflected to the cache. Try refreshing the instance when you check for changes

```
SalarySupplementModel ssm = em.find(SalarySupplementModel.class, ssm.getId()); 
em.refresh(ssm);
```

Do this in the method where you expect fresh data.

Comment: I was unsuccessful. I get error message saying the object is not managed.

Comment: Try then with this `ssm = em.find(SalarySupplementModel.class, ssm.getId()); em.refresh(ssm);`

Comment: Wow.  That finally worked for me.  Thanks a lot mate, you just made my day. :)